# How do you determine graded versus abrupt diode junction types?

Tags: diodes

#### The problem

When a diode is reverse biased with 8V, it has a junction capacitance of 15pF.
When the reverse biased is increased to 12V, the capacitance drops to 13.05pF.
Find whether it's abrupt or graded junction.

#### The solution

The capacitance of abrupt junction diode varies inversely with the square root of applied voltage. If it's abrupt type, then:

$$C_{12} = C_8\sqrt{\frac{8}{12}} = 15\sqrt{\frac{8}{12}} = 12.24 \; pF$$

The capacitance of graded junction diode varies inversely with the cube root of applied voltage.
If it's graded type then:

$$C_{12} = C_8\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{12}} = 15 \sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{12}} = 13.10 \; pF $$

Therefore, the given diode is graded junction type.

Now for my puzzlement, I didn't understand what is the criterion from which they deduced that it's a graded type and not an abrupt type, can some please explain?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you want to know why the capacitance has that functional form?  (The abrupt is the easiest, both involve solving Poisson's equation in the depletion region.) This may help,http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter4/ch4_3.htm

Comment: I want to understand, how did they deduce that it's graded junction and not abrupt? and how did they infer it from their calculations?

Comment: Ahh, 13.10 pF is closer to what they measured 13.05 pF than 12.24 pF. (But I'm guessing that will not satisfy you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The junction capacitance of a reverse biased diode is given by

$$C = \frac{C_0}{ (1 + V_R/ V_0) ^ m }$$

Where

\$C_0\$: Capacitance at No applied voltage

\$V_0\$: Junction or built in potential

\$V_R\$: Applied reverse bias

\$m\$: Grading coefficient = \$1/2\$ for abrupt and \$1/3\$ for step graded junction

The rest is all math. Simply divide the two equations, one for 15 pF and other for 13.05 pF, and take the logarithm. The result is 0.33. So it is graded.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Its hard to put it that way on mobiles.

Comment: So if in any case we were close to 15pF it would be abrupt. Or the closer the fraction is to 1 then we have abrupt, less than 0.5 then it would be graded. Is it something like this?

Comment: They didn't calculate for 13.05 pF, only for 15 pF.

Comment: OK, I think I can see. Correct me if I am wrong but we plug in both cases 15pF, and because we were close to 13.05 in graded junction coeffeicient that means that we have graded junction. I understand it now, thanks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0V4TZAyd8I

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist . Actually, the proper way was to assume m as unknown, and calculate it. First use the equation in my answer above for 15pF, then for 13.05 pF. Next, divide both of them. The result comes out --> 1.15 = (1.5) ^ m . Take log with base 1.5 to get m = 0.334